# what is the use of custom event arg?

Tags: c#, mvvm

Here is the code for custom event args. I am confuse about use of those and also role of those. I can not understand  this property `public object AddedObject { get; private set; }` the code is here :

```
public class ObjectAddedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ObjectAddedEventArgs(object addedObject)
    {
        AddedObject = addedObject;
    }

    public object AddedObject { get; private set; }
}
```

I can not understand use of the get and set property of added object. Please explain to  me.

Answer (score 1):

The `AddedObject` property is what is called an "auto property", which simply means that the C# compiler will generate a private variable to hold the value of the property. The "get" is the mechanism which allows you to read the value of the property. The "set" is the mechanism which allows you to set the value of the property, although in this case since the set is `private` you aren't able to set the value. This translates to code which would look roughly like this:

```
private object _AddedObject;
public object AddedObject
{
   get { return this._AddedObject; }
   private set { this._AddedObject = value; }
}
```

The class itself (the `ObjectAddedEventArgs` class) is used to provide additional data (the `AddedObject` value) to an event handler which, presumably, would access that data and do something with it as part of it's response to the event.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx):

> EventArgs is the base class for classes containing event data.

....

> This class contains no event data; it is used by events that do not
>   pass state information to an event handler when an event is raised. **If
>   the event handler requires state information**, the application must
>   derive a class from this class to hold the data.

That being said, the original developer of that class intended to handle events and at the same time making the object `AddedObject` available to the event handler method. See the website above for a nice example.

Comment: While deriving from EventArgs is not required by the compiler it is strongly encouraged by the Microsoft style guidelines.

Comment: @DanBusha you are right, you don't have to derive from it. However, you are encouraged to do so in case you want your event handler to have state info.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that state can be passed with an event using any object irregardless if it derives from EventArgs, but for convention's sake it _should_.

Answer (score 0):

the good thing when you declare your events like this

```
  event EventHandler<ObjectAddedEventArgs> MyObjectAddedEvent;
```

you can subscribe to it in a weak manner easily

```
    myObjectInstance.MyObjectAddedEvent += new EventHandler<ObjectAddedEventArgs>(MyObjectAddedEventMethod).MakeWeak(eh => d.MyObjectAddedEvent -= eh);

    private void MyObjectAddedEventMethod(object sender, ObjectAddedEventArgseventargs)
    {
        //do something with the event args
    }
```

the weak stuff you find [here](http://diditwith.net/2007/03/23/SolvingTheProblemWithEventsWeakEventHandlers.aspx).